# Automake Yacc Problem

Tags: c, yacc, automake

I am working on a project using Yacc and Lex. I'm using Anjuta IDE for the task, and I encountered problem with Autotools. I can't build my source code, because my files require header produced by Yacc. How can i make sure that Yacc does its work, before the rest of the compilation process.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your lex and yacc files as dependencies so make will make them:

```
foo_SOURCES : foo_main.c foo.y foo.l
```

or something like that.  More details would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a header file, produced by Yacc's `-d` option, you should list it in `BUILT_SOURCES` so that it is built before any other source file is compiled.

A `Makefile.am` could look like

```
 BUILT_SOURCES = parser.h
 AM_YFLAGS = -d
 bin_PROGRAMS = foo
 foo_SOURCES = ... parser.y ...
```

(This example is copied verbatim from [the Automake manual](http://sources.redhat.com/automake/automake.html#Yacc-and-Lex).)